# ObjectScript Library.FileBinaryStream convert into a string

Tags: intersystems-cache, objectscript

How can I create a string a from binary stream? I tried StreamGet and OutputToDevice class methods but that is not returning the string. Is there another class I should use

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `stream` is a `%Library.FileBinaryStream`:

```
set string = stream.Read($$$MaxStringLength)
```

Note that string can't be more than 7mb, while stream can be bigger.

Comment: 7mb is a strange value to use. They can't be longer then $$$maxStringLength. Standard thats around 32k characters, but can be bigger according to configuration settings.

Comment: what if it is a Ens.StreamContainer? Can I still using stream.read

Comment: @Mcdevitt you'll need to call `Read()` of `Stream` property.